# How to make animated intro?

Tags: theme-development, customization

There are a few websites that I stumble upon now and then that have animated intros like the one here: www.monotwo.com

How do I do that in WordPress?

And how would I integrate this into a customs theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/

or you can research follow these keywords to know more detail.

- how to use CSS3 transitions
- how to animate out a full-screen preloader
- how to combine CSS3 with JavaScript for this technique

Answer (score 2):

Monotwo uses SVG + JS for their animation, exported from Adobe CS (probably After Effects or Animate). [See Creating a vector animation for the web in a post-Flash world](https://thislittleduck.com/blog/svg-animation-using-snap-svg/) for more info about this process.

You could also animate using Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop, Sketch, Hype - search for "vector animation" to find tools and techniques that fit you.

How do you do this in WordPress, and in a custom theme? Place your exported code in a [static front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating%20a%20Static%20Front%20Page) by using `front-page.php`.